# Can I execute a bookmarklet in the context of a child window?

Tags: javascript, popup, cross-domain, bookmarklet

I would like to open an external site in a popup window, then execute a bookmarklet on that popup window from the parent window's bookmarks bar. I can't figure out how it could be done, though, for other than maybe simple tasks like changing the popup window's document.location. Is it possible in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, same origin policy would be in play. Browser has no clue that the JavaScript was from a bookmarklet or a script on the page.